# Using multithreading to encrypt files simultaneously

Tags: multithreading, encryption

> If I have 1 thread encrypting video for 60s
>
> Can I encrypt 1000 videos
>
> On 1000 thresds
>
> In 60s? If so, why/how?

This is from a technical interview. The answer seems to be yes, but I cant say why.

If you run 1000 threads, then wouldn't CPU processing/power be divided in all 1000? So my answer was no.

Help?

Comment: Depends entirely on the hardware. But without more info I would have picked 'no' as well.

Comment: If you're asking about a realistic view, then the bottleneck is likely the speed of the storage and not the encryption speed. Even if you have 1000 CPUs (one thread per CPU), you still needs to distribute the 1000 video files across the machines and their CPUs. Do you account for that delay? Are all the CPU homogeneous? Is the storage homogeneous?

Comment: If you've got your videos on a spinning hard drive, trying to read/write to so many files at once is going to cause the drive's heads to seek back and forth a lot, making the process much slower than it would be in the single-file case.  If we ignore the drive's performance (e.g. if you have an SSD), there is still the issue of the CPU<->RAM bridge, which is likely to be another bottleneck.  Even if you have 1000 cores on your CPU, it's likely they will be all contending for the same bandwidth to RAM, and will slow each other down as they compete for bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

The answer only depends on the number of cores you have on you computer. In case you got 1000, yes you can.

Comment: But he doesn't (have 1000 cores) so the answer is No.

Comment: You never know :D

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a silly question fom the interviewer in my opinion.

If we assume the only resource bottleneck to encrypt is cpu(not realistic - think about io).

If we also assume you have a 1000 core machine.

And lastly assume that one thread completely consumes a core for the entire 60s then in theory, if you parallelized the code to run a 1000 threads you could encrypt 1000 videos in the 60s.

Personally I think there are a few crazy assumptions in this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like these kind of questions in interviews - or these kind of interviews in general.

But I guess this is more about the theoretical side of things. The idea behind the question is that the encryption routines are not dependent on each other. So I guess the answer is yes.

This can also be easily deduced by the final "If so, why/how?". Even if you would answer "no" then you seem not allowed to clarify your answer.

---

Of course there can be any kind of "buts" that can be raised. What if the encryption key is on a smart card and cannot be duplicated? What if there aren't 1000 cores at your disposal? What if you have a severe cache-hit when using multiple cores? What if the input device is a disk rather than fast memory?

But this all doesn't invalidate the fact that yes, it *is* certainly possible.